# How to install menu bar in Ubuntu Browser

Tags: default-browser

Two questions:  How do I import bookmarks from firefox to ubuntu browser. Second question, how do I get a menu bar to show in Ubuntu Browser.  Thanks, Carol

Comment: The Ubuntu Browser is obviously designed for Ubuntu Touch, if what you want is a browser that uses the blink render engine you can use Chromium/Google Chrome/Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when you say ubuntu browser you actually mean firefox, all you have to do is sign into sync. There it will sync all your settings. To get into sync, click on the menu icon (the button the the top right corner) and on the near the bottom you will see a bar that says

> Sign into sync

click on that, sign into your account or create a new one (if you don't have one already, then you should create the account on the firefox with all your personalizations already made), follow any other directions it gives you,  and walla. All your settings are sync'd and ready to use